Explaining why the determinant of M is non-zero
Show that the determinant of
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&1&\cdots&1\\1&0&1&1&\cdots&1\\1&1&0&1&\cdots&1\\1&1&1&0&\cdots&1\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\1&1&1&1&\cdots&0\end{pmatrix}$$
is nonzero.
Solution I was provided: If the above matrix is $n\times n$ then
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&\cdots&1\\1&0&1&\cdots&1\\1&1&0&\cdots&1\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\1&1&1&\cdots&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}n-2&-1&-1&\cdots&-1\\-1&n-2&-1&\cdots&-1\\-1&-1&n-2&\cdots&-1\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\-1&-1&-1&\cdots&n-2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-(n-1)&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&-(n-1)&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&-(n-1)&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&-(n-1)\end{pmatrix}$$
Clearly the determinant of the right hand matrix is just the product of the diagonal entries, which is nonzero $(n$ is assumed to be at least 3). Since for any square matrices $A$ and $B,\det(AB)=$ $\det(A)\det(B)$, we must have that the determinant of both matrices on the left hand side are nonzero as well.
Can someone explain how does the solution work, I don't get why we multiply M by this specific matrix? And why does it only work for n greater than 3, not 2?

What makes you say that it doesn't work for $n = 2$? (It should be clear why it doesn't work for $n=1$, esp if you write it out.)

But why does it say "n is assumed to be at least 3". Also why the choice of this matrix in particular, if the goal is to get a diagonal matrix? Can it be done with a different one or is this uinque? I don't think this proof is rigorous though

1/ Maybe because that's what the original problem says? EG The problem could have asked us to prove this for (say) $n = 100$.  2/ Clearly if $ AB = D$ diagonal matrix, then $ A(kB) = kD$ still a diagonal matrix for any real $k$. Note that if such a matrix exists, then $B = k' A^{-1}$ is uniquely determined up to a scalar. 3/ The goal (of this approach) isn't necessarily to get to a diagonal matrix, but simply to get to a matrix where we can show that the determinant is non-zero. Then, $ \det(A)\det(B) = \det(D)$, so if $\det(D) \neq 0$, then $ \det(A) \neq 0$.

Observe that $(M+I)^2=n(M+I)$ and deduce that $M$ is inversible, so its determinant is nonzero.

A similar question has been asked some days ago here. In fact, up to a complete reversal of the columns (which is an invertible operation), it is the same problem...

The matrix is of the form $M=N-I,$ where $N$ is the matrix with all terms equal  $1.$ The eigenvalues of $N$ are equal $n$ and $0.$ The eigenspace corresponding to $n$ is one dimensional and contains $(1,\ldots,1)^t.$ The eigenspace corresponding to $0$ has dimension $n-1$ and consists of vectors whose sum of the terms is equal $0.$  Therefore the eigenvalues of $M=N-I$ are equal $n-1$ and $-1,$ with eigenspaces described above. Hence  $M$ is invertible.
The determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues. Thus $\det M=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1).$
Remark The determinant can be calculated directly. First add all rows $2,\ldots,n$ to the first row. In the new matrix  subtract the first column from all other columns. The resulting matrix is lower triangular with $n-1$ at the upper left corner and with $-1$ on remaining part of the diagonal.

More generally, if $f(x)$ is a polynomial with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, then the eigenvalues of $f(M)$ are $f(\lambda_i)$.  You are establishing this result for $f(x)=x-1$.

@RobertShore I am not establishing this, nearly obvious, result, but applying it.
